# HttpClient not working for multipart/form-data

Tags: c#, multipartform-data

I'm trying to make a multipart/form-data post request to **telegram's public bot api** to send photo and stuff, but after an entire day of tries I have not managed to make any progess.

```
                    var MultipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                var FormUrlContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(Parameters);
                MultipartContent.Add(FormUrlContent);

                if (File.Exists(MultipartParameter.Object2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Creating byte array for file...");
                    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + MultipartParameter.Object1 + " - Value: " + MultipartParameter.Object2);
                    MultipartContent.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(MultipartParameter.Object2)), MultipartParameter.Object1);
                } else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File does not exist!");
                }

                Console.WriteLine(MultipartContent.ToString());

                HttpResponseMessage Message = await Client.PostAsync(Url, MultipartContent);

                var res = await Message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return res;
```

Here is what I've done so far.
Now MultipartParameter.Object1 is the name of the file parameter
And MultipartParameter.Object2 is the path to the file.
The thing is that it is just not working! It does not give me an error and no result string. But if I put a .EnsureSuccessStatusCode() method it gives me an exception with no stacktrace...

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: "not working" is bad.... what is your exception message ?

Comment: There is no _exception_ thats the problem.

Comment: @Nick how far through this does it get? Do any of your console writes appear?

Comment: Also, try removing the `MultipartContent.ToString()` I've got a feeling that it's flushing the buffer before it gets posted.

Comment: @Soviut yes it does! I dont knwo why it is not executing the request.

Comment: It does what? You need to edit your answer and more carefully explain how much of your code is working. Also, share any details about what your server is receiving on the other end when you post.

Comment: @Soviut the 'Console.WriteLine(...)' that I've put in for debug reason work.  The thing is: it is not working and does not give me any errors. That is the bit of code that is not working. And also, I've sad that I'm trying to use the telegram public bot api.

Comment: You're not getting errors because you're sending out an http request without checking for a status. That's what the `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` throws an exception. You're not getting a stack trace from it because the error is directly related to the fact that an error code was returned from the server. Nothing in your code failed, the http response was just an error.